# Zend Framework - Doctrine 2 integration : where to store the EntityManager?

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am integrating Zend Framework and Doctrine 2.

The question is, in my controllers and view, in need to access the model. I can do all this through a **single instance of the EntityManager**.

**Where do I store this instance ?**

- `Zend_Registry` ? That's where it is now, it is accessible from everywhere, but not really practical : `$em = Zend_Registry::get('EntityManager');`
- As a controller and view property ? That would be accessible as `$this->em`, I like this
- Create a factory class that will return the instance ? `$em = My\EntityManager\Factory::getInstance();`. Encapsulation is good, but long to type...
- Is the `EntityManager` a Singleton already ? -> (*update*) not it is not

Comment: The entity manager is not a singleton. It's possible to use several entity managers to deal with distinct databases in the same request.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info, question updated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using the EntityManager directly in your Controllers and Views. Instead, use a Service layer and inject the EntityManager it that.

I have two custom action helpers, one to retrieve Repositories and one for Services. Each action hold a reference to the EntityManager and inject it accordingly before handing it back to the Controller.

Not my actual code but something like this (not tested):

**My/Controller/Action/Helper/Service.php**

```
<?php

namespace My\Controller\Action\Helper;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class Service extends \Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{

    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function direct($serviceClass)
    {
        return new $serviceClass($this->em);
    }

}
```

You can write a similar Action Helper to retrieve Repositories.

Then, register the helper in your bootstrap (where we also have access to the EntityManager):

```
<?php

use Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker as HelperBroker,
    My\Controller\Action\Helper\Service;

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

    public function _initActionHelpers()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('doctrine');
        $em = $this->getResource('doctrine');

        HelperBroker::addHelper(new Service($em));
    }

}
```

Now write a simple Service.

**My/Domain/Blog/Service/PostService.php**

```
<?php

namespace My\Domain\Blog\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
    My\Domain\Blog\Entity\Post;

class PostService implements \My\Domain\Service
{

    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function createPost($data)
    {
        $post = new Post();
        $post->setTitle($data['title']);
        $post->setContent($data['content']);

        $this->em->persist($post);
        $this->em->flush(); // flush now so we can get Post ID

        return $post;
    }

}
```

And to bring it all together in a controller action:

```
<?php

class Blog_PostController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    private $postService;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->postService = $this->_helper->Service('My\Domain\Blog\PostService');
    }

    public function createPostAction()
    {
        // normally we'd get data from the actual request
        $data = array(
            "title" => "StackOverflow is great!",
            "content" => "Imagine where I'd be without SO :)"
        );
        // and then validate it too!!

        $post = $this->postService->createPost($data);
        echo $post->getId(); // Blog post should be persisted
    }

}
```

Comment: In the Service action helper above you'll want to extend Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract, not Zend_View_Helper_Abstract.

Answer (score 4):

Since the `EntityManager` is usually created and configured during bootstrap - either as the return value of an explicit `_initDoctrine()` call or by using an application resource - storing it in the `Bootstrap` seems to make the most sense to me. Then inside a controller, it is accessible as:

`$em = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getResource('doctrine');`

I see a lot of examples of accessing bootstrap via the front controller singleton:

`$em = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')->getResource('doctrine');`

which has the advantage that works everywhere.

Comment: This is the best option, you should avoid using Zend_Registry where possible. Though I wouldn't recommend using within any Zend Framework components; the EntityManager should only be used by Services and Repositories.

Comment: @Cobby : What are "Services and Repositories" ? Thanks

Comment: @David `$em = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')->getResource('doctrine');` is a very long line to type ! It can get very boring ;)

Comment: @Matthieu Check out [this blog post](http://cobbweb.me/2010/11/integrate-doctrine-2-zend-framework-application/) and [Doctrine Ref Guide](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html?highlight=repository#custom-repositories) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837489/using-doctrine-2-and-repositories-what-would-be-the-purpose-of-a-service-layer/5844654#5844654).

Comment: @Matthieu Indeed, very long. Way too long. As in @Cobby's second link, I'd probably use it only once, either in a controller's `init()` method or in an action helper.

Comment: @Cobby : Thanks ! I realize I should be using the EM in Services, not controllers and views... Please create an answer so I can accept it, I think its important for anyone else that has the same question.

Comment: @Cobby - Are you kidding? The best option??? Why would the perfectly independent Zend_Registry be worse then Zend_Controller_Front with zillion dependencies? How about testing your services?

Comment: I think you might have misread my first comment. Storing the EM in Zend_Registry OR Zend_Controller_Front are both bad IMO, and my solution doesn't do this. My services have NO Zend Framework dependencies and can just be instantiated with an EntityManager as they are plain classes - this makes them super easy to test. Please see the accepted answer (written by me) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the integration provided by the Bisna package, written by one of the Doctrine 2 contributes. It is at https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/ZendFramework1-Doctrine2

It allows you to configure Doctrine in your **application.ini**. It uses an application resource plugin to process the ini settings.  I have written documentation for Bisna. It may be integrated into the package by the time you read this. If not, you can find it at https://github.com/kkruecke/ZendFramework1-Doctrine2, in the **bisna-documentation/html** subdirectory of that package.  I have also put the documentation a http://www.kurttest.com/zfa/bisna.html (although this may be temporary).

Answer (score 0):

I store the Entity Manager in Zend_Registry and then I've also created an action helper which I call in my controllers.

Answer (score -2):

Zend_Registry i think is a goods idea.

Basically it is a bad idea to access EM from view, if your really need this feature, your can create a view helper, and use it

Comment: Accessing the EM from the view or via Zend_Registry is a bad idea. The view shouldn't deal with the EM directly -- Zend_Registry is a bad idea because it is no better than a global variable; however, it can be used in a non-global-static manner, but that isn't what we are talking about here :)

Comment: I didn't say that it is a good way to use Zend_Registry direct from view, and also about EM. I said that for views need helpers